# Select encadeado usando somente HTML e jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, Comunidade!

Eu tenho dois selects em HTML um com as regiões do Brasil e outro com os estados. Como eu faço para encadeá-los sem usar um modelo (PHP, Java, C# etc), somente com HTML (os selects) e jQuery?

```js
//select regiao/estado encadeados/dependentes
$('#regiao').on('change', function(){
    var regiao = $(this).val(), estado = $('#uf');
    // filtrar os estados de acordo com a regiao selecionada
});
```

```html
<!-- select com as regiões do Brasil -->
<select id="regiao" name="regiao">
    <option value="CO">Centro-oeste</option>
    <option value="NE">Nordeste</option>
    <option value="N">Norte</option>
    <option value="SE">Sudeste</option>
    <option value="S">Sul</option>
</select>

<!-- select com os estados do Brasil -->
<select id="uf" name="uf">
    <option value="AC" class="N">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL" class="NE">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP" class="N">Amapá</option>
    <option value="AM" class="N">Amazonas</option>
    <option value="BA" class="NE">Bahia</option>
    <option value="CE" class="NE">Ceará</option>
    <option value="DF" class="CO">Distrito Federal</option>
    <option value="ES" class="SE">Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="GO" class="CO">Goiás</option>
    <option value="MA" class="NE">Maranhão</option>
    <option value="MS" class="CO">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="MT" class="CO">Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="MG" class="SE">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="PA" class="N">Pará</option>
    <option value="PB" class="NE">Paraíba</option>
    <option value="PR" class="S">Paraná</option>
    <option value="PE" class="NE">Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="PI" class="NE">Piauí</option>
    <option value="RJ" class="SE">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="RN" class="NE">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
    <option value="RS" class="S">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="RO" class="N">Rondônia</option>
    <option value="RR" class="N">Roraima</option>
    <option value="SC" class="S">Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value="SP" class="SE">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="SE" class="NE">Sergipe</option>
    <option value="TO" class="N">Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pessoal, como uso a função "Executar trecho do Código" ao perguntar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os browsers comportam-se de maneiras diferentes a interagir com `select`.  Há um [bug conhecido no Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17203826/2256325), e por isso não vai dar para fazer só assim:

```
$('#regiao').on('change', function() {
    var classe = this.value;
   $('#uf option').each(function() {
        var opt = $(this);
        if (opt.hasClass(classe)) opt.show();
        else opt.hide();
    });
});
```

Testei também assim:

```
$('#regiao').on('change', function() {
    var classe = this.value;
    var options = $('#uf option').remove();
    options.each(function() {
        var opt = $(this);
        if (opt.hasClass(classe)) opt.show();
        else opt.hide();
    });
    $('#uf').append(options);
});
```

Que retira e repõe as options do `select`, para o obrigar a reagir. Primeiro retira, depois esconde e mostra o que deve comparando o `value` do `select` mudado com a `class` no segundo `select`, e depois repõe tudo.

Porém esta solução não funciona no Safari 9...

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj7z3vpd/

#### Então fui mais agressivo e fiz assim:

```
var options = $('#uf option');
var uf = $('#uf').empty();
$('#regiao').on('change', function() {
    var classe = this.value;
    var opts = options.filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass(classe)
    });
    uf.html('').append(opts);
});
```

esvaziando o `select` a cada `change` do outro `select`, tendo sempre as `option` originais guardadas numa variável e filtrando as que devem ser adicionadas a cada vez.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj7z3vpd/3/

Comment: no seu exemplo, a última opção (no caso, Tocantins) sempre é carregada mesmo sem ter a classe selecionada e quando a página carrega todos os estados estão disponíveis. Tem alguma forma de corrigir isso?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida para mim funciona bem no Chrome mas a testar no Safari não funcionou (!)... então mudei o código assim -> https://jsfiddle.net/mj7z3vpd/3/ funciona como precisas?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado, @Sergio!

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer isso:

```
$('#regiao option').on('click', function(){
    var value = $( "#regiao option:selected").val();
    $('#uf option').css('display', 'none');
    $('.' + value).css('display', 'block');
    $('#uf').val($('.' + value).eq(0).val())
})
```

Optei por o evento `click` nos `options` ao invés do `change` no `select`.

### Passos

**1.** Ele irá capturar o valor do `option` selecionado no primeiro `select`.

**2.** Irá apagar dar um `display: none` em todos os `options` do `select#uf`.

**3.** Irá dar um `display: block` ao todos `options` com a `class` correspondente ao `value` do primeiro `select`.

**4.** O valor do `select#uf` será o `value` do primeiro `option` com a classe correspondente.

### **Funcionando**

```js
$('#regiao option').on('click', function(){
  var value = $( "#regiao option:selected").val();
    $('#uf option').css('display', 'none');
    $('.' + value).css('display', 'block');
    $('#uf').val($('.' + value).eq(0).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- select com as regiões do Brasil -->
<select id="regiao" name="regiao">
    <option value="CO">Centro-oeste</option>
    <option value="NE">Nordeste</option>
    <option value="N">Norte</option>
    <option value="SE">Sudeste</option>
    <option value="S">Sul</option>
</select>

<!-- select com os estados do Brasil -->
<select id="uf" name="uf">
    <option value="AC" class="N">Acre</option>
    <option value="AL" class="NE">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="AP" class="N">Amapá</option>
    <option value="AM" class="N">Amazonas</option>
    <option value="BA" class="NE">Bahia</option>
    <option value="CE" class="NE">Ceará</option>
    <option value="DF" class="CO">Distrito Federal</option>
    <option value="ES" class="SE">Espírito Santo</option>
    <option value="GO" class="CO">Goiás</option>
    <option value="MA" class="NE">Maranhão</option>
    <option value="MS" class="CO">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
    <option value="MT" class="CO">Mato Grosso</option>
    <option value="MG" class="SE">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="PA" class="N">Pará</option>
    <option value="PB" class="NE">Paraíba</option>
    <option value="PR" class="S">Paraná</option>
    <option value="PE" class="NE">Pernambuco</option>
    <option value="PI" class="NE">Piauí</option>
    <option value="RJ" class="SE">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="RN" class="NE">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
    <option value="RS" class="S">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
    <option value="RO" class="N">Rondônia</option>
    <option value="RR" class="N">Roraima</option>
    <option value="SC" class="S">Santa Catarina</option>
    <option value="SP" class="SE">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="SE" class="NE">Sergipe</option>
    <option value="TO" class="N">Tocantins</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pessoal, como uso a função "Executar trecho do Código" ao perguntar?